# Which is the most secure IPC?

Tags: c, sockets, ipc, unix-socket

I'm writing a C program in which I have a client and a server both on the same machine running on two processes. I don't know much about IPC and I was wondering which is the most secure way to let them communicate, both under Windows and Unix. What I would like to have is a "channel" in which only the two mentioned processes can read/write and no one else can, so that I can avoid encryption. Is it possible?

At first I tought about socket, but I immediately realized that it isn't secure. Then I discovered Unix Domain Socket and I'm oriented in that way but again I don't know much. I've read about ancillary data: is there a way to use them to control the access to the socket file and let only the two processes to use it?

Comment: @J... I would like to avoid encryption if possible in some way. I'm protecting data sent by the client (such as passwords) from any other process that could sniff the traffic between client and sevrer.

Comment: If the client and server are running on the same machine, an attacker would have to have access to the machine. If that's the case, then you should pack it in - they will get the data.

Comment: @AndreaRubi: UNIX domain sockets are protected by file system permissions. Given that this is mainly about security I would recommend to ask instead at [security.se]. But you need to be more specific what you want to protect from: different user on same machine, different process with same user ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details what data you want to protect against what types of attacks and how exactly the processes are started. On UNIX, root can always use a system call trace to see unencrypted data transferred via the IPC channel.

Comment: A true problem is how to authenticate the other side of the communication link.

Answer (score 0):

First some basics about security:

- if the machine can do it, anyone logged as admin can too
- any admin can setup hooks about anything and consult traces later
- security in absolute is philosophia and not Information Technology. In real world, you first set up a threat model, including who the attackers can be and want (accident like loss of power is an *attacker*), and then search how to mitigate (or accept) the risks
- you normally do not allow accesses or privileges to executables but to the account under which they run, the reason why admins cannot be restrained (not at all under Unix and Unix-like, and partly under Windows)

That being said, a common and rather portable IPC way is a mere pipe, provided one of the processes can start the other one.